# How to use assertTrue?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I have:

```
package com.darlik.test;

import org.junit.Assert;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        assertTrue(1, 2);
    }

}
```

package with org.junit is set and working but in line with assertTrue i have error:

> The method assertTrue(int, int) is undefined for the type Test

Why? I use Eclipse.

Comment: `assertTrue` has the method signature `assertTrue(boolean)`, i.e. `assertTrue(actual == expected)`, see http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertTrue%28boolean%29

Comment: why use main? Please annotate with test, makes more sense, even in example. Second thing, you don't have appropriate import. Please fix import as suggested by @Reimeus + change what you are comparing inside

Comment: @MichalGruca Good point - also remember to rename the class since it conflicts with `org.junit.Test`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[`assertTrue`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertTrue(boolean)) is based on a single boolean condition. For example

```
assertTrue(1 == 2);
```

You need to import the statement statically to use

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
```

Typically, however `assertEquals` is used when comparing 2 parameters, e.g.

```
public class MyTest {

   @Test
   public void testAssert() throws Exception {
        assertEquals(1, 2);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

From the doc : [assertTrue(boolean)](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertTrue(boolean)) or [assertTrue(String, boolean)](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertTrue(java.lang.String,%20boolean)) if you want to add a message.

AssertTrue assert that a **condition** is true, you still have to code such condition for it to be **evaluated** at runtime.

Answer (score 7):

You have to specify the class that defines that method:

```
Assert.assertTrue(condition);
```

Furthermore you're calling the method with 2 parameters which makes no sense. [`assertTrue`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertTrue(boolean)) expects a single boolean expression.

Although you can also do this by using a static import:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
```

which will allow you to call it as `assertTrue(condition);` instead.

Answer (score -1):

Better try assertThat with matchers. Check this blog about it https://objectpartners.com/2013/09/18/the-benefits-of-using-assertthat-over-other-assert-methods-in-unit-tests/

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

....

    @Test
    public void testNum() {
       assertThat(repo.getNum(), is(equalTo(111)));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Delete the **module-info.java** file if there is any in the project. It's not necessary and is only used if you're using Java's built-in module system.