# how to matches double quotes in java?

Tags: java, regex, string

See the code below. My question is **why the assertion failed**? Thanks!

```
@Test
public void test_name() {
    String s = "\"name\":\"alice\"";
    Assertions.assertTrue(s.matches("\"name\":"));
}
```

**EDIT AND THE ANSWER**

Thanks, @James McLeod. The `regex` in `s.match(regex)` is used to match the whole `s`, but not substring of `s`.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25352329/how-to-use-asserttrue

Comment: Because it doesn’t match. Try “\”name\”:.*”

Answer (score 0):

"\"name\":.+" OR "\"name\":.*" would do